# UpdateExpression to flatten the record

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have such items in Dynamo DB:

```
[{
  "Id": "1",
  "Data": {
    "Value": "test"
  }
},
{
  "Id": "2",
  "Data": {}
},
{
  "Id": "3"
},
{
  "Id": "4",
  "Data": {
    "Wrong": "234"
  }
}]
```

And I'm trying to make it flatten, but for the `Data.Value` field only:

```
[{
  "Id": "1",
  "Value": "test"
},
{
  "Id": "2"
},
{
  "Id": "3"
},
{
  "Id": "4"
}]
```

My Update request looks like this:

```
var request = new UpdateItemRequest {
    TableName = "<table>",
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {{"Id", new AttributeValue("<item-id>")}},
    UpdateExpression = "SET #a = #c.#a REMOVE #c",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"#c", "Data"},
        {"#a", "Value"}
    }
};
```

This works well for Id = 1 and 3. But does not work for 2 and 4. I assume because it can not do a SET. It does not throw any errors, but simply does not delete the `Data` attribute.

Is there a way to make it in a single call?

Comment: I can suggest an almost-but-not-quite solution: You can use in UpdateExpression `SET #a = if_not_exists(#c.#a, :empty) REMOVE #c`. This will be similar to what you wanted, except that Value will be set to and empty string instead of remaining missing. Unfortunately I couldn't think of a way not to add this empty string.

Comment: Can you cleanup data using Regex? Something like this.

string input_string = "[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Data\" :{\"Value\":\"test\"}},{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Data\":{}},{\"Id\":\"3\"},{\"Id\":\"4\",\"Data\":{\"Wrong\":\"23 xyz\"}}]";
input_string = input_string.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace(" : ","").Replace(": ", "").Replace(" :", "");           
input_string = Regex.Replace(input_string, "(?:\"Data\":)\\{(.*?)\\}", x => x.Value.Replace("\"Data\":{", "").TrimEnd('}'));
input_string = input_string.Replace(",}", "}");

Comment: @NadavHar'El eventually, empty value will not work

Comment: @deeptowncitizen I realize that the solution with an empty value was not the one you wanted, but please consider whether maybe it can be good enough for you - in which sense will it "not work"? In any case, when you use the resulting data, you'll probably filter out data with missing Value - but you can with the same ease filter out data with an empty Value. The const difference (to store the tiny empty Value) will be very small.

Comment: I understand the difference is not too large, but I have constraints that do not allow me to follow this approach. The example was added intentionally...

Answer (score 0):

you just need a condition with your expression, to check if the attribute exist or not, thats it.

```
    ConditionExpression ="attribute_exists (#c.#a)"
```

For more détails in Amazon doncs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).

Comment: In his example, he wanted the empty "Data" to be removed from item 2. This can't be done with your ConditionExpression proposal. Only if he gives up this requirement - and agrees that Data only gets deleted if it had a Data.Value - then your solution is good.

Comment: yes, eventually this approach does not work. I've tried it previously